# I would please like to know how to initialize a bidimenstional array of a custom type in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, initialization, immutability

Here is the specific example:

```
enum Segments {
    case s1, s2, s3, noParent, empty
}

struct StructA {
    var id: Segments = .empty
    var parent: Segments = .empty
    var value = 0.0
}

class ClassA {
    let StructAMap: Array<Array<StructA>> = []

    init {
    for help in 1...2 {
        StructAMap[help][1].id = Segments.s1
        StructAMap[help][1].parent = Segments.noParent
        StructAMap[help][1].value = 0.0
        StructAMap[help][2].id = Segments.s2
        StructAMap[help][2].parent = Segments.s1
        // etc...

     }
     StructAMap[1][3].id = Segments.s1
     StructAMap[2][3].value = 3.0 
     // etc...
     }
}
```

If I try this, I get this error: cannot assign to immutable value of type 'Segments'

If I change StructAMap to var it doesn't really work, but I get less error messages
This is a map of the structure and won't be changed; which is why I wanted it as a constant.

Thanks so much.

Update: Comment #1

That seems to solve some of the error mistakes and is pretty clever. So now I am trying that in a playground. I want to test that the map is working, and I'm getting an execution failure:

```
enum Segments {
    case s1, s2, s3, noParent, empty
}

struct StructA {
    var id: Segments = .empty
    var parent: Segments = .empty
    var value = 0.0
}

class ClassA {
    let StructAMap: Array<Array<StructA>>

    init() {
        var StructAMap: Array<Array<StructA>> = []
        for help in 1...2 {
            StructAMap[help][1].id = Segments.s1
            StructAMap[help][1].parent = Segments.noParent
            StructAMap[help][1].value = 0.0
            StructAMap[help][2].id = Segments.s2
            StructAMap[help][2].parent = Segments.s1
        }
        StructAMap[1][3].id = Segments.s1
        StructAMap[2][3].value = 3.0
        self.StructAMap = StructAMap
    }
}

var paciente1 = ClassA()

println("\(paciente1.StructAMap[1][1])")
```

Console output:

Playground execution failed: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
* thread #1: tid = 0xcea9d, 0x000000010c09a14e PlaygroundLogger`Swift.Array.subscript.nativePinningMutableAddressor (Swift.Int) -> A + 238, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
  * frame #0: 0x000000010c09a14e PlaygroundLogger`Swift.Array.subscript.nativePinningMutableAddressor (Swift.Int) -> A + 238
    frame #1: 0x0000000116937e3f $**lldb_expr74`__lldb_expr_74.ClassA.init (self=0x00007f905a5000e0)() -> __lldb_expr_74.ClassA + 1695 at MyPlayground.playground:122
    frame #2: 0x0000000116938444 $__lldb_expr74`__lldb_expr_74.ClassA.__allocating_init ($metatype=0x000000011693ac40)() -> __lldb_expr_74.ClassA + 116 at :0
    frame #3: 0x00000001169370df $__lldb_expr74`main + 223 at MyPlayground.playground:134
    frame #4: 0x000000010bb32710 MyPlayground
    frame #5: 0x000000010bb365f1 MyPlayground`reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned () -> (@unowned ()) to @callee_owned (@in ()) -> (@out ()) + 17
    frame #6: 0x000000010bb351f1 MyPlayground`partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned () -> (@unowned ()) to @callee_owned (@in ()) -> (@out ()) + 81
    frame #7: 0x000000010bb36620 MyPlayground`reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@in ()) -> (@out ()) to @callee_owned () -> (@unowned ()) + 32
    frame #8: 0x000000010bb36657 MyPlayground`reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned () -> (@unowned ()) to @callee_unowned @objc_block () -> (@unowned ()) + 39
    frame #9: 0x000000010c17f41c CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 12
    frame #10: 0x000000010c175165 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    frame #11: 0x000000010c174923 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 851
    frame #12: 0x000000010c174366 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    frame #13: 0x000000010c222661 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRun + 97
    frame #14: 0x000000010bb32dc2 MyPlayground`main + 1714
    frame #15: 0x000000010ee0d145 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #16: 0x000000010ee0d145 libdyld.dylib`start + 1

Update 2:

I think I figured out a way to tweak a little bit further.

```
class ClassA {
    let xSize = 6 // whatever
    let ySize = 6 // whatever
    static let StructAMap: Array<Array<StructA>> = {
        var tempStructAMap = Array(count: ySize, repeatedValue: 
                         Array(count: xSize, repeatedValue: StructA()))
        for help in 1...2 {
            tempStructAMap[help][1].id = Segments.s1
            tempStructAMap[help][1].parent = Segments.noParent
            tempStructAMap[help][1].value = 0.0
            tempStructAMap[help][2].id = Segments.s2
            tempStructAMap[help][2].parent = Segments.s1
            // etc...

        }
        tempStructAMap[1][3].id = Segments.s1
        tempStructAMap[2][3].value = 3.0
        // etc...
        return tempStructAMap
    }()
}
```

Comment: The problem is that when you do `StructAMap[help][1].id = Segments.s1` the `help` variable is at 1 so `StructAMap[help]` means "second object of the array" but this object doesn't exist since your `StructAMap` is an empty array of empty arrays. And even if this object existed, the second object called with `StructAMap[help][1]` wouldn't exist either yet. // It may help if you explained what you're trying to achieve (why the loop and why the nested arrays).

Comment: This is a map of a structure. Each segment has a name, a parent to which it connects and a value. All segments have only one parent, although they may have more than one descendent. This map doesn't change. Each segment can assume a different state (like open) and this state propagates along its descendents. The struct to record state is mutable, but it doesn't need to know the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In init(), build the array using a local var and then assign it to instance constant:

```
class ClassA {
    let xSize = 6 // whatever
    let ySize = 6 // whatever
    let StructAMap: Array<Array<StructA>>

    init() {
        var StructAMap = Array(count: ySize, repeatedValue: 
                         Array(count: xSize, repeatedValue: StructA()))
        for help in 1...2 {
            StructAMap[help][1].id = Segments.s1
            StructAMap[help][1].parent = Segments.noParent
            StructAMap[help][1].value = 0.0
            StructAMap[help][2].id = Segments.s2
            StructAMap[help][2].parent = Segments.s1
            // etc...

        }
        StructAMap[1][3].id = Segments.s1
        StructAMap[2][3].value = 3.0
        // etc...
        self.StructAMap = StructAMap
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, because of another issue: the array is empty so when you access any slot in it it will raise an index out of bound exception

Comment: But doesn't the init() fill in the array?

Comment: I have updated the example creating the needed array slots – look at the line with `var StructAMap = `

Comment: From the documentation I could not figure out how to use the (count, repeatedValue) and that you could put a type as the repeatedValue. Thanks again.